# how to select 0th index if value not found in kendoui combobox

Tags: combobox, indexing, kendo-ui

I have created kendoComboBox

```
jQuery("#" + id).kendoComboBox(
        {
            filter: "contains",
            change: changecallback
        }).trigger("change");

var changecallback = function () {
        //var combobox = jQuery("#" + id).data("kendoComboBox");
        if (this.selectedIndex == -1) {
            this.selectedIndex = 0;
            this.trigger("change");    
            return;
        }
        this.select(this.selectedIndex);
    };
```

what i want to do is to select 0th index if the value entered is not found `(this.selectedIndex == -1`) in options. where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [select](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#select) method. You can try it using the [API](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/api.html) demo of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$combobox.select(0);
```